Ho do I filter by multiple methods in network tab of Firefox?
I can only filter by one request method at a time like this:
method:GET
Which lets the Network panel only show GET requests:

Though I want to filter by more than one method, e.g GET and POST, so both GET and POST requests are shown at the same time but requests with other methods not.
I have tried:

method: GET || POST
method: GET or POST
method:GET, method:POST
method: GET, POST

None of these worked. Any ideas?

There doesn't seem to be a direct way to do that right now, so I've created a feature request for OR combinations in the filters.
Having said that, the field allows you to exclude a property by prepending it with a minus, e.g. -method:OPTIONS. And those filters can be combined. So if you have GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE requests, you can filter the other ones out by writing -method:PUT -method:DELETE to only see GET and POST requests.
